# C++ two-way operators, is it possible?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

For example, we have this class:

```
class my_class
{
public:
  friend my_class operator* (const my_class&, int a);
  friend my_class operator* (int a, my_class&);  
};

my_class operator* (int a, my_class&)
{
    // do my_class * a
}

my_class operator* (int a, my_class&)
{
    // do a * my_class
}
```

is it possible to do just one operator* to do what these two do?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the second form return `my_class`?

Comment: The first one can do `my_class * a` but the first one only does `my_class * my_class` if it's a member function or otherwise a compiler error because global operator functions need two arguments.

Comment: What is the semantics you actually intend? Multiplying, Dereferencing?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Mutiplying! I just wrote a quick question, sorry for semantic errors!

Comment: @marquesm91 _"I just wrote a quick question,"_ Keep in mind, this site is intended to be helpful for future researchers when hitting questions. Would you consider your question to be so for anyone else not seeing what code you actually have, which semantics was intended? Go over your to improve question please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ think on what you said, I improved my question, sorry for the hurry!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do that. However, you can implement one and simply call it from the other one:

```
my_class operator *(const my_class &l, int r) {
    // implement the actual operator here.
}

my_class operator *(int l, const my_class &r) {
    return r * l;
}
```

(Note that you cannot implement the latter function as part of the class. You have to do it externally. The first function can be implemented as an instance method, because its first argument is of the class type.)

Comment: Thanks, this will help me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can implement one by using the other:

```
my_class operator*(int lhs, const my_class& rhs)
{
    return rhs * lhs;
}
```

if the operation itself is **commutative**. This is not always the case, so be careful.

There are also libraries to help you with certain operators. If you have

```
my_class mc, a, b;
a = mc * 1;
b = 1 * mc;
```

you probably also want to be able to do something like

```
mc *= 1;
```

In that case you only implement

```
my_class& my_class::operator*=( int v );
```

and you can use [Boost.Operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/operators.htm) or [df.operators](https://github.com/d-frey/operators/) to generate the other operators automatically.

Example:

```
struct my_class
    : df::commutative_multipliable< my_class, int >
{
    // ...

    my_class& operator*=( int v )
    {
        // ... implement me!
        return this;
    }

    // ...
};
```

In this example you again only implement *one* operation and the rest is generated using a common schema.